# Make footer editable in PyroCMS

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm relatively new to `PyroCMS` so I may be asking the wrong question. I have a website, mostly content driven. There are a few different `layout` files that we've created (maybe 8 of them). The problem is that each `layout` file is completely distinct and relies on a `partial`:

```
{{ theme:partial name="axiumfooter" }}
```

But I want the admin to be able to edit the footer. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way of doing this would be to add a new page, add the content you want, and then use the pages template tags to pull the content of the page into your footer.

```
{{ pages:chunk id="1" name="default" }}
```

The id is the page id which you can get on the synopsis window in the Pages section of PyroCMS, and the name relates to the page chunk.

The problem you might have is that you now have a separate page with your footer content in it, but you could redirect away from this using the redirect utility (/admin/redirects).

Comment: This approach is generally frowned upon as you are making the entire system revolve around one page, which magically contains content that appears in the footer. This is not what page chunks were meant to do, and I have been against this usage for a while. You can use Widget Areas or HTML widget instances for this. Really, Variables should be renamed to Chunks and allow Field Type support. Thats on the list for 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

In what way you want the admins to be able to do just that? Would a theme editor do the job, where you can browse your theme and partials, or you're looking for something more custom? PyroCMS is relatively easy to extend and adapt to your wishes, so almost everything is possible (although not out of the box).